# How to check if two arrays are equal even if they contain NaN values in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to compare two arrays. It just so happens that the data for the arrays contains `NaN` values and when you compare arrays with `NaN` values, the results are not what I would have expected.

```
julia> a = [1,2, NaN]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
   1.0
   2.0
 NaN  

julia> b = [1,2, NaN]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
   1.0
   2.0
 NaN  

julia> a == b
false
```

Is there an elegant way to ignore these `Nan`'s during comparison or replace them efficiently?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`isequal`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.isequal):

> Similar to `==`, except for the treatment of floating point numbers and
>   of missing values. `isequal` treats all floating-point `NaN` values as
>   equal to each other, treats `-0.0` as unequal to `0.0`, and `missing` as
>   equal to `missing`. Always returns a `Bool` value.

```
julia> a = [1,2, NaN]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
   1.0
   2.0
 NaN  

julia> b = [1,2, NaN]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
   1.0
   2.0
 NaN  

julia> isequal(a, b)
true
```

Comment: oh I see this will be the fastest and optimal solution!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use `isequal(a, b)` (which also treats `missing` equal to `missing`, but `-0.0` as unequal to `0.0`).

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out the NaN's on each array:

```
a = [1, 2, NaN]
filteredA = filter(x -> !isnan(x), a)

b = [1, 2, NaN]
filteredB = filter(x -> !isnan(x), b)

print(a == b)
print(filteredA == filteredB)
```

You could then create a function that does the filtering, and a custom compare function that uses the filtering function on both arguments and compare. Not sure if there is a more Julia-esque way.

Answer (score 1):

Or create a new type. And create a Singleton `nan` which you use instead of NaN.

```
struct MyNaN end
nan = MyNaN()
```

and write a function for replacing `NaN`s by it.

```
with_nan(l) = map((x) -> if isnan(x) nan else x end, l)
```

Then you can wrap your lists using this function.

```
a = [1, 2, NaN]
b = [1, 2, NaN]
with_nan(a) == with_nan(b)
## true
```